# JNI code and Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()

Tags: java, c++, memory, jvm, java-native-interface

Does `Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()` also include memory allocated by JNI code or does it only include memory that is allocated by Java objects? Furthermore, does the C++ code also has to fit into the memory that was assigned to the JVM or is it independent from the JVM?

Comment: [`totalMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#totalMemory()): “Returns:
the total amount of memory currently available **for current and future objects**, measured in bytes.” [`freeMemory()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runtime.html#freeMemory()): “Returns:
an approximation to the total amount of memory currently available **for future allocated objects**, measured in bytes.” In other words, no code, no native memory, no I/O buffers—unless they affect the memory available for objects.

Answer (score 0):

`Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory()`:
The memory includes all objects of the JVM and the allocation of some JNI objects.

In the Java runtime data area there are native method references to C++ objects or Java objects in the heap.

All objects are allocated on the heap.